# $(...).insertFusionCharts is not a function in angular using jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, fusioncharts

I am using these scripts in my angular project

```
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom-script.js"></script>.
```

In the custom-script.js, I am calling the Fusion chart using jquery. But I am getting the error that insertFusionChart is not a function. here is code for custom-script

```
$(".chart-container").insertFusionCharts({
        type: "spline",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        dataFormat: "json",
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                //"caption": "Average Monthly Temperature in Texas",
                //"yaxisname": "Average Monthly Temperature",
                "anchorradius": "7",
                //"plottooltext": "Average temperature in $label is <b>$dataValue</b>",
                "showhovereffect": "1",
                "showvalues": "1",
                "numbersuffix": "",
                "theme": "candy",
                "anchorbgcolor": "#00e0c8",
                "palettecolors": "#00e0c8"
            },
            "data": [
                {
                    "label": "Sun",
                    "value": "10"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Mon",
                    "value": "35"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Tue",
                    "value": "25"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Wed",
                    "value": "45"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Thu",
                    "value": "55"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Fri",
                    "value": "65"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Sat",
                    "value": "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

I am using this data to create the fusionchart

Comment: Show your component code

Comment: In HTML file the code is,<div class="default-left chart-outer">
                <div class="chart-container"></div>
            </div> And simple ts file is just created

Comment: Actucally you have to add this jquery  code in the component.

Comment: I had tested it now by placing in the component file. Yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Please share full project otherwise i will not help you

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved.
The js files were not added to my project.
Then change the scripts files from index.html to the angular.json file